Implementing VIT Attention Rollout with PyTorch's Vision Transformer
I'm trying to implement VIT Attention Rollout from github Vit Explain using PyTorch's Vision Transformer model, but I'm encountering an IndexError: list index out of range error. This error seems to be related to the fused_attn attribute in the attention mechanism.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
def load_model(weight_path, device):
    model = torchvision.models.vit_l_16()
    model.heads = torch.nn.Linear(
        in_features=model.heads.head.in_features, out_features=2)
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(
        weight_path, map_location=torch.device(device)))
    model.eval()
    return model

model = load_model(weight_path=path, device=device)
img = preprocess_image(image_path)
attention_rollout = VITAttentionRollout(model, head_fusion="max", discard_ratio=0.9)
mask = attention_rollout(img)

Error Message
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[48], line 2
      1 attention_rollout = VITAttentionRollout(model, head_fusion="max", discard_ratio=0.9)
----> 2 mask = attention_rollout(img)

Cell In[46], line 130
    127 with torch.no_grad():
    128     output = self.model(input_tensor)
--> 130 return rollout(self.attentions, self.discard_ratio, self.head_fusion)

Cell In[46], line 75
     74 def rollout(attentions, discard_ratio, head_fusion):
---> 75     result = torch.eye(attentions[0].size(-1))
     76     with torch.no_grad():
     77         for attention in attentions:

IndexError: list index out of range

I found a similar issue with the vit_explain library from GitHub, where the problem was resolved by setting attn.fused_attn = False for each block in the model. However, I'm using PyTorch's built-in Vision Transformer model, which doesn't have this attribute.
the question is

How can I implement a similar fix (setting fused_attn = False) for PyTorch's Vision Transformer model?
Is there a way to convert the PyTorch Vision Transformer architecture to use the timm library, which has the fused_attn attribute?
Are there any other approaches to resolve this IndexError when implementing VIT Attention Rollout with PyTorch's Vision Transformer?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
